# How to get line number from grep?

Tags: command-line, grep

The following grep

```
grep -r -e -n coll *
```

will display

```
fullpath/filename:  <tag-name>coll</tag-name>
```

I would like to know what line has the following text, I tried adding `-n`, but it did not work. I tried adding  `| grep -n *`, but it did something weird.

What I would like to see (I don't care about format) is

```
fullpath/filename:10:  <tag-name>coll</tag-name>
```

Comment: I see line numbers when using the `-n` option. Can you post the output of what you get?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should put `-e` at the end of the options list: `grep -rne coll *`

Answer (score 21):

no need for -r & -e !

get line number of a pattern!

```
grep -n "pattern" file.txt
```

if you want to get only the line number as output add another grep command to it !

```
grep -n "pattern" file.txt | grep -Eo '^[^:]+'
```

Comment: To get just the line number, it's easier to use `cut`, e.g. `cut -f1 -d:`

Answer (score 3):

To grep a pattern in a specific file, and get the matching lines:

```
grep -n <Pattern> <File> | awk -F: '{ print $1 }' | sort -u
```

or using `cut` as suggested by @wjandrea:

```
grep -n <Pattern> <File> | cut -f1 -d: | sort -u
```

where

- `<Pattern>` is a quoted glob pattern (use option `-E` for regexp);
- `<File>` is the file you are interested in;
- the first pipe `awk ...` filters the line numbers in the output of grep (before `:` on each line);
- the second pipe ensures that line numbers only appear once.

Comment: To get just the line number, it's easier to use `cut` than Awk, e.g. `cut -f1 -d:`

Comment: @wjandrea Easier in what way?

Comment: I mean the syntax is simpler

Comment: Why the `sort`? How can a line appear more than once?

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 Are you asking how a pattern can appear more than once on a line?

Answer (score -1):

```
#This shows only the line number.
#i --> case-insensitive, n --> line number

var="APPLE";targetFile="targetFile.txt"
numLin=$(grep -in $var $targetFile | cut -d':' -f1);
echo $numLine;
```

Comment: I guess there is a type in line 5 : `numLin` should be `numLine`, like in the next line.